# Algebra with three operators

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why do we not extend our notions of algebra to include the power operator? + * and ^.

We have groups which effectively just have +, and fields which have + and *.

For a field K, a + 0 = a, a * 1 = a, + and * are commutative and a(b + c) = ab + ac.

Why don't we have a formulation for an object which also has ^? a ^ 0 = 1, a ^ 1 = a, 0 ^ a = 0, 1 ^ a = 1, a ^ (b + c) = (a ^ b) * (a ^ c).

Or did my three years of degree maths and 25 years since make me oblivious to something that is well studied?

The wikipedia page on exponentials talks about this to some extent, but doesn't really seem to formalise it.

Comment: See [Exponential rings and fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_field).

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque! Do people still publish books on these subjects? Or is it all just on line these days?